# How to add 2 wysiwyg field in same form in back office

Tags: magento-1.9, backend, wysiwyg, tinymce

I need to insert two wysiwyg fields with tinymce in my backend module in the same form.

It's working when I insert only one with this code in the edit tab form:

```
$fieldset->addField('mother', 'editor', array(
    'name'      => 'mother',
    'label'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Mother content'),
    'title'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Mother content'),
    'style'     => 'height:12em;width:30em',
    'required'  => true,
    'wisiwyg'   => false,
    'config'      => Mage::getSingleton('cms/wysiwyg_config')->getConfig()
));
```

and this one in the editAction in the controllers

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setCanLoadExtJs(true);
if (Mage::getSingleton('cms/wysiwyg_config')->isEnabled()) {
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setCanLoadTinyMce(true);
}
```

But when I try to insert a second one, chrome doesn't load tinymce and crashes (unable to close the tab in chrome, I need to use windows task management to cancel the chrome process). Maybe a JS conflict? I can't even access the console in chrome...

[EDIT after comment] And below the maybe problematic code for the second wysiwyg field

```
$fieldset->addField('content', 'editor', array(
    'name'      => 'content',
    'label'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Main content'),
    'title'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Main content'),
    //'style'     => 'height:36em;width:30em',
    'required'  => true,
    'wisiwyg'   => true,
    'config'      => Mage::getSingleton('cms/wysiwyg_config')->getConfig(),
));
```

Comment: can you show the code you use to add the second editor? It may have something to do with the id and/or name of the field.

Comment: Hi, i just edited my question with the informations you asked fore, let me please know if you've an idea

Comment: Exactly what I suspected. I'm in the middle of my answer now. Come back in 5 minutes. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the `$fieldset` variable comes from something like this:

```
$fieldset = $form->addFieldset(....)
```

where `$form` is `$form = new Varien_Data_Form();`
I mean, this is the standard way of doing it. If it's not standard, it's the one mostly used.

Try adding this right after initializing the `$form` variable.

```
$form->setHtmlIdPrefix('something_here_');
```

Now, why this might work.
The id of the element added in the form is generated based on the first parameter you pass to the method `addField`.
So your code will generate a text area with the id `content` in this case.
And there is already an element with the id `content` in the DOM. it's a `div` that wraps almost all the page content.
And the editor is trying to position itself on that div instead of the textarea and fails miserably.

Adding the line `$form->setHtmlIdPrefix('something_here_');` will make all elements in the form to have the id `something_here_some_id` instead of `some_id`. And you avoid the conflicts.

In conclusion, the problem is not that you add 2 editors in the page. Is the name of the second one. You can easily test this, but removing the first editor and leaving just the second one with the name `content`. The page will still crash.

Comment: this is working : perfect! Thanks a lot !
(for the record i i took this code from the mage cms page form declaration wich also use content as a key, that's why i didn't suspect a key problem)